# AJAX/ASP.NET Core MVC/DevExtreme POST back returns bad url (Error/Error?code=22)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, devextreme

I am using Ajax in my MVC application to send a POST back when you click the logout button. I want to send the user back to the Login page and route them to the HttpPost metod in the controller. However, in my Ajax code, I am getting an error when I click logout : `This localhost page can’t be found  No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost/myApp/Error/Error?code=22`

PageHeader.cshtml

```
...
 items.Add()
        .Widget(w => w
        .Button()
        .Type(ButtonType.Normal)
        .StylingMode(ButtonStylingMode.Text)
        .Text("Logout")
        .ID("logoutbutton")
        .OnClick("logoutOnClick")
            )
            .CssClass("toolbar-button")
            .LocateInMenu(ToolbarItemLocateInMenuMode.Auto)
            .Location(ToolbarItemLocation.After);
    })
    )
...
<script type="text/javascript">
        function logoutOnClick () {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?')) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")'
                    
                });
            }
        }
</script>
```

AccountController.cs

```
...
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login() { return View(new LoginModel()); }

     
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Login(LoginModel userModel)
        {
            bool? isAuthenticated = false;

           ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
>     public IActionResult Login(LoginModel userModel)
> ```

According to your code since you are using the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute to prevent the prevent forgery of a request. When using JQuery Ajax calls the above method, you should also add the RequestVerificationToken in the request header.

In the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method, configure the antiforgery service:

```
        //configure the antiforgery service to look for the X-CSRF-TOKEN header. To prevent the cross-site request forgery.
        services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

Then, in the Login.cshtml page, in the Ajax beforeSend function, set the RequestVerificationToken:

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.LoginModel
 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Login">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            ...
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" value="Create" id="btnCreate" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnCreate").click(function () { 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Account/Login',
                    type: 'Post',
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    data: { "UserName": "AA", "Password": "pass" },
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("sucess");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status) {
                        alert(status);
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Then, we can access the action method via Ajax, screenshot like this:

[image]

Besides, you can also remove the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute in the controller, then, there is no need to set the RequestVerificationToken in the request header.

Code like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginModel userModel)
    {
        bool? isAuthenticated = false;
        return View();
    }
```

JQuery script:

```
        $.ajax({
                url: '/Account/Login',
                type: 'Post', 
                data: { "UserName": "AA", "Password": "pass" },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("sucess");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(status);
                }
            });
```

Reference: [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix ajax url:

```
  url:  "/MyApp/Account/Login",
```

And I can't see any data: in your ajax